# datatables language won't load

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a datatable set up on my website, fully working and styled. However, I don't seem to be able to change the language output. I found [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mke35Lrk/) JSFiddle on a different stack overflow question, and my code worked fine in it.

my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.datatable').dataTable({
    "olanguage":{
        "sProcessing": "Bezig...",
        "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ resultaten weergeven",
        "sZeroRecords": "Geen resultaten gevonden",
        "sInfo": "_START_ tot _END_ van _TOTAL_ resultaten",
        "sInfoEmpty": "Geen resultaten om weer te geven",
        "sInfoFiltered": " (gefilterd uit _MAX_ resultaten)",
        "sInfoPostFix": "",
        "sSearch": "Zoeken:",
        "sEmptyTable": "Geen resultaten aanwezig in de tabel",
        "sInfoThousands": ".",
        "sLoadingRecords": "Een moment geduld aub - bezig met laden...",
        "oPaginate": {
            "sFirst": "Eerste",
            "sLast": "Laatste",
            "sNext": "Volgende",
            "sPrevious": "Vorige"
        }
    },
    "sPaginationType": "bs_normal"
});

$('.datatable').each(function () {
    var datatable = $(this);
    var length_sel = datatable.closest('.dataTables_wrapper').find('div[id$=_length] select');
    var search_input = datatable.closest('.dataTables_wrapper').find('div[id$=_filter] input');

    search_input.attr('placeholder', 'Zoek');
    search_input.addClass('form-control input-sm');
    length_sel.addClass('form-control input-sm');

    datatable.bind('page', function (e) {
        window.console && console.log('pagination event:', e)
    });
});
```

});

I have also tried

```
"language": {
        "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/Dutch.json"
    },
```

which led to the same result; worked on the fiddle, didnt work in my script.